# Select checkboxes to filter result matching all selections

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 3 checkboxes that toggle between results. It works as is, however, I would like to be able to filter with multiple checkboxes at the same time.

For example, if `high` and `bread` are ticked, it should only display one result as this only matches one of the `divs`. At the moment it is displaying anything with either `high` or `bread`.

https://jsfiddle.net/f7srx0dd/12/

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="High" data-category-type="high">High
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="low" data-category-type="low" > 
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="low" data-category-name="bread" > 

<div id="Categories">
    <div class="hide" data-category-type="high" data-category-name="pizza">high</div>
    <div class="hide" data-category-type="low" data-category-name="pasta">low</div>
    <div class="hide" data-category-type="low" data-category-name="pizza">low</div>
    <div class="hide" data-category-type="high" data-category-name="bread">bread</div>
</div>

$('.checkbox ').on('click', function (e) {



var $this = $(this),
    $links = $('.checkbox');

if ($this.hasClass('selected')) {
    $this.removeClass('selected');
} else {
    $this.addClass('selected');
}

$('#Categories > div').hide();
var anySelectedCheckbox = false;
$.each($links, function (k, v) {

    $this = $(v);

    if ($this.hasClass('selected')) {
        anySelectedCheckbox = true;
        var cat = $this.data('categoryType');
        var nam = $this.data('categoryName');
        $('#Categories > div[data-category-type="'+cat+'"]').show();
        $('#Categories > div[data-category-name="'+nam+'"]').show();
    }

});

if(!anySelectedCheckbox) {
$('#Categories > div').show();

}


});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do this by keeping a running filter of which ones match the checkboxes. Start by selecting all the results as a jQuery object. Then, for each checkbox, filter the jQuery object to only match those specific ones:

```
var selectedDivs = $('#Categories > div').hide();
var anySelectedCheckbox = false;
$.each($links, function (k, v) {

    $this = $(v);

    if ($this.hasClass('selected')) {
        anySelectedCheckbox = true;
        var cat = $this.data('categoryType');
        var nam = $this.data('categoryName');
        selectedDivs = selectedDivs.filter('[data-category-type="'+cat+'"], [data-category-name="'+nam+'"]');
    }

});
selectedDivs.show();
```

Comment: I've tried updating the fiddle with this code and it doesn't seem to work? Am I missing something?

Comment: My mistake. I needed to select with a comma, so it's either type or name. Try now.

Comment: would you please be able to update the fiddle? I can't seem to get it to work